# ksql-server metric name missing underscore after service id

Tags: ksqldb

I use the JMX exporter provided by confluent.

https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts/blob/master/charts/cp-ksql-server/templates/jmx-configmap.yaml

The problem is after defining `service id` as `ksql_click_live`, the metric name presents as 
`cp_ksql_server_metrics_confluent_ksql_ksql_click_livebytes_consumed_total` that `_` is missing between the service id and the metric name.

I think the `service id` does not append the metric properly. A workaround is to add `_` after the service.id, but then the topic name also has one more `_`.

Is there a better approach than adding `_` after the service.id?

Comment: Probably best raised as a bug (or PR :) ) at https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/

Comment: issue created and PR sent https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/pull/3085